# Rails -- h.simple_format fix

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

This is my code:

```
 = h.simple_format(item.text.text, class: 'basic')
```

And `item.text.text` is `"<p><span style=\"color: rgb(251, 213, 181);\">asdasdasd</span></p>"`, but when I see the view which was rendered in inspect, the `style=\"color: rgb(251, 213, 181);\"` attribute goes away!

How to fix this! (Note: I need `class: 'basic'`!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`simple_format` from `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` has default option `sanitize: true`

> Sanitizes the html by converting  and  tags into regular text, and removing all "onxxx" attributes (so that arbitrary Javascript cannot be executed). It also removes href= and src= attributes that start with "javascript:". You can modify what gets sanitized by defining VERBOTEN_TAGS and VERBOTEN_ATTRS before this Module is loaded.

To prevent deleting style attribute:

```
simple_format(item.text.text, { class: 'basic' }, sanitize: false)
```

`<p>` inside `<p>` is invalid in all standards of HTML because the opening `<p>` tag will automatically close the `<p>` element:

```
#item.text.text => "<p><span style=\"color: rgb(251, 213, 181);\">asdasdasd</span></p>"

simple_format(item.text.text, { class: 'basic' }, sanitize: false, wrapper_tag: "div")
#=> "<div class=\"basic\"><p><span style=\"color: rgb(251, 213, 181);\">asdasdasd</span></p><div>"
```

Comment: Doesn't turning off sanitize leave you open to a XSS attack?

Comment: @max, attribute `style` inside a tag `<span>` that changes dynamically, make the author open to a XSS attack if options are coming from users. If someone for that will be use `raw`/`html_safe` - not protected to a XSS attack. But when content sanitized and then wrapped in `span` with some `style` attributes - all ok.

Comment: But disabling sanitize would allow a malicious user to add for example a `onclick` attribute or `onload` attribute.